# Which joomla module choose to create screencasts?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I have a task from the client to create a screncasts website. It must be similar to egghead.io or laracasts.com. I decided to choose Joomla for a basis. And for this reason, I want to know are there components or modules for Joomla, which realize similar video functionality? For example, the site has two types of screencasts. Paid and free. If the video is paid, then at the opening, instead of showing, the user must to pay. (All like on laracasts.com). This is the main point. Thank you.

P.S. Perhaps there is a better solution for this kind of site?

Comment: So you need a component to store videos some of then will be open to a certain user and the other one will be for a more restricted number of users. I don't think there's an existing solution for this, you probably need to customize a component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project has 3 different aspects.

1. User management
2. Managing payments and memberships
3. Video display

1.For the first point Joomla ACL (Access Control Level) provides good built-in functionality to filter user access. You can create different user groups (free memberships, paid, pro etc.) and use acl to control access to the content.
 2.Managing payments. There are many components that do this (free and paid), you can search on extensions.joomla.org 
Akeeba subscriptions is a good one for managing subscriptions.
3. Video playing. You can do anything from simple to complex. Basic solution is to embed the video in an article using standard html5 tags. A better solution, is to use a content builder extension like K2 that has additional features to handle multimedia content. It makes editing and content creation easier for non specialists. 
Or you can build or find a specialized component that will handle all these aspects in one solution.